# I used springboot to integrate rabbitmq and encountered Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I used springboot to integrate rabbitmq and encountered Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present

I'm using

RabbitMQ 3.12.4

Erlang 26.0.2

Is there any way to quickly locate it?

environment:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
 <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <mybatis-plus.version>3.4.2</mybatis-plus.version>
        <hutool.version>5.0.6</hutool.version>
        <redisson.version>3.15.6</redisson.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>1.27</snakeyaml.version>
        <protostuff-api>1.0.10</protostuff-api>
        <zkClient.version>0.1</zkClient.version>
        <apache.httpclient.version>4.5.9</apache.httpclient.version>
        <rabbit.client.version>5.6.0</rabbit.client.version>
        <apache.commons.version>3.12.0</apache.commons.version>
        <fastjson.version>1.2.51</fastjson.version>
        <springboot.version>2.7.8</springboot.version>
    </properties>
<dependency>
<dependencyManagement>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
                <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
                <version>${rabbit.client.version}</version>
            </dependency>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

Error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gateWayInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gateWayInterceptor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'identityCheck'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'identityCheck': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'imUserService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'imUserServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageProducer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageProducer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rabbitTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactoryBeanConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$201/20514539.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at cc.topsystem.im.service.ServiceApplication.main(ServiceApplication.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gateWayInterceptor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'identityCheck'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'identityCheck': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'imUserService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'imUserServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageProducer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageProducer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rabbitTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactoryBeanConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$201/20514539.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'identityCheck': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'imUserService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'imUserServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageProducer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageProducer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rabbitTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactoryBeanConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$201/20514539.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'imUserServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageProducer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageProducer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rabbitTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactoryBeanConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$201/20514539.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageProducer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rabbitTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactoryBeanConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactoryBeanConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactoryBeanConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactoryBeanConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$201/20514539.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 110 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:94)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:284)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:282)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:513)
    at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:291)
    at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:107)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1323)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.getResolvableType(DependencyDescriptor.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.checkGenericTypeMatch(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:864)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:823)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    ... 120 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CredentialsRefreshService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 152 common frames omitted
```

I tried to upgrade the springboot version, but it didn’t work after the upgrade.

Comment: Firstly, you should use the most recent bugfix version of Spring Boot (currently 2.7.19) instead of a version that is nearly one year old. Secondly, do not override dependency versions that are managed in the Spring Boot Parent pom unless you know what you are doing. I guess amqp-client 5.6.0 (released in January 2019) is just not compatible with Spring Boot 2.7.x. Spring Boot 2.7.17 uses amqp-client 5.14.3 instead